# Using tf.switch_case or tf.case with string condition

Tags: tensorflow, if-statement, tensorflow2.0

I am learning tensorflow and have some trouble implementing things that are otherwise easy.

I have a toy function:

```
def function(fruit, b):
    if fruit == 'apple':
        return b        
    elif fruit == 'banana':
        return b+2        
    else:
        return b*3
```

The case syntax is:
tf.case(pred_fn_pairs, default=None, exclusive=False, strict=False, name='case')
where pred_fn_pairs refers to a tuple of (condition, output) and I have trouble rewriting the condition in a fully tensorflow way since it is a string.

How would the above function be written using only tensorflow?

Answer (score 3):

Did you know that `tensorflow 2.0` is awesome? use `@tf.function`:

```
@tf.function
def function(fruit, b):
    if fruit == 'apple':
        return b        
    elif fruit == 'banana':
        return b+2        
    else:
        return b*3
```

`tf.autograph` will convert it to a tensorflow graph for you under the hood! Woohoo.

If you still want the native tensorflow ops:

```
def function(fruit, b):
  tf.cond(tf.equal(fruit, 'apple'), lambda: b, tf.cond(tf.equal(fruit, 'banana'), lambda: b+2, lambda: b*3))
```

Comment: wow, really? so tf.function the works exactly like the native syntax? under the hood, I mean - it is completely and totally the same?

Comment: Well -  it's same, but different, but the same. `@tf.function` takes native python code and converts it to a tensorflow graph. The functionality is the same, but it's calculated differently (and faster). Autograph can't convert all native python code. E.g., you can't use python variables defined outside of the function, and you can't use packages because `@tf.function` can't convert them. You can compare it to `cython`, which takes python code and compiles it to `C` code to make it faster. The functionality is the same, and it's still python, but the code executed is `C` code.

Comment: ok, i think I understand... I have a followup question in regards to native implementation then. Based on your suggestion I use tf.case in the following way:
tf.case([(tf.math.equal(fruit, 'apple'), f1(var)), (tf.math.equal(fruit, 'banana'), f2(var))], default=f3(var), exclusive=True)
However, I get the following error:
AttributeError: Tensor.name is meaningless when eager execution is enabled. Not entirely sure what this error even means...

Comment: I suppose by `tf.eq` you mean `tf.equal`, also, you should replace `b` by `lambda: b`, `b+2` by `lambda: b+2` and `b*3` by `lambda: b*3`... For the TF version, if you have many if/else, you can use [`tf.case`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/case) instead of nesting `tf.cond` ops, like `tf.case([(tf.equal(fruit, 'apple'), lambda: b), (tf.equal(fruit, 'banana'), lambda: b + 2)], default=lambda: b * 3)` (or, if using integers, better [`tf.switch_case`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/switch_case)).

Comment: About [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function), you can see the graph created for a function with `get_concrete_function`, e.g. you can do `print(function.get_concrete_function(tf.constant('apple'), tf.constant(2)).function_def)` and see the TF ops for that function. Interestingly, if you just do `print(function.get_concrete_function('apple', 2).function_def)` (regular Python values, not TF tensors), then the function is considered to have no tensor inputs, and so it becomes simply a constant value. So you get something of a "best of both worlds".

Comment: tnx, @jdehesa ! since your answer with tf.case is the most direct answer to my question - do you mind posting it as an answer and not comment so that I can mark it as 'accepted'?